# Qt VS Tools uic issue

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have tried to build my test project using `Visual Studio 2017` version 15.9.17 with `Qt VS Tools`. It fails with uic error. I use `Qt 5.13.1` on Windows 10.

**Error description:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   1   uic (C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017\bin\uic.exe) TestAppVSEx ...\TestAppVSEx\testapp.ui  1
```

**Build output:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestAppVSEx, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Generate moc_predefs.h
1>Uic'ing testapp.ui...
1>Moc'ing testapp.h...
1> Could not create output file
1>testapp.ui : error 1: uic (C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017\bin\uic.exe)
1>Done building project "TestAppVSEx.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

The test project works well using `Qt Creator`. I am curious why it fails to build using `VS 2017` with `Qt VS Tools` extension installed? It is the `Qt VS Tools` extension bug with the latest `VS 2017` version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @drescherjm Hello! Ok. I have added the build output. My form only has 1 button. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain well. My question had nothing to do with your code at all. I was asking you about checking the Output Tab of Visual Studio instead if the Errors List. Many times the output tab has more detailed information.

Comment: @drescherjm My build output is from the Output Tab of Visual Studio, please check out this screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/BP6PSMS/VS-output-window.gif and currently, it does not provide useful information. Thanks.

Comment: Could not create output file may be the problem. Possible permissions problem or uic outputting to the wrong folder. I am not sure. Hopefully someone else has an idea.

Comment: @drescherjm

Hello! I have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `$(IntDir)\uic\%(RelativeDir)` as the Output Directory.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Now it compiles successfully. Thank you.